# php-fpm.conf error logging options

Tags: php, php-fpm

I've noticed that php-fpm's configuration files can take the option `error_log`, but I also see `php_admin_value[error_log]` used. What's the difference?

Also, the PHP manual says that the `log_errors` flag "[tells whether script error messages should be logged to the server's error log or error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors)", but I don't know how to interpret that. Does `log_errors = off` mean no error logging, or that errors will go to apache/nginx's log (as opposed to being logged by php-fpm)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php_admin_value[error_log] to specify where save php logs and log_errors just tell if you what enable or disable php logs

You can enable or disable php logs from php-fpm whit ( as you can enable or disable it from php.ini )

```
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

And tell when save it:

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php.log
```